# How can I use dynamic uploaded images in Next.js?

Tags: docker, next.js, docker-compose, nextjs-image

I have created app, users can upload pictures. But when user upload picture, it goes to public folder. It's not working after I dockerize my next.js, because public folder doesn't support dynamic uploads. That's why I have changed my uploads directory. Now it's not accessible from Docker, how can I fix this issue ?

Comment: I think the only way to make it work is to store the images on an external services like S3 (or a custom one) and get a public URL from it. Alternatively, you could store it in a DB and have an API fetching it.

Comment: I want to store it in my folder and its path in my database. I think next.js was not good choice

Comment: The problem is also docker. Storage is ephemeral if you don't mount a volume so it would disappear after a restart. Also, if you need to run multiple instances, one would not have access to the file of the other (again without mount configured). As a rule, I don't use storage in docker for file uploads even though you could make it work but usually no (or few) advantages.